# Building all app flavors at once in android

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-flavors

I work on a project, where i have around 20+ flavors, it is very time consuming when it comes at making the builds of each flavor, I want to automate this process, I simply want to loop through my each flavor and build their .apk and .aab files one by one.
Please help me with any article or your own suggestions.

I asked a question from android development and i expect some professional android developer to respond to it.

Comment: you can use assemble's gradle command from the terminal

Comment: Have you tried the command `./gradlew assemble`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the release build try this command

> ./gradlew assembleRelease